# Why is chrome not picking up my proxy setting immediately?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I'm on windows, I have written a script which will switch the proxy setting of internet options by changing values in registry. I can confirm that the proxy setting is changed successfully, but chrome doesn't pick up the new proxy immediately, I use `chrome://net-internals/#proxy` this link to check, the proxy setting will remain as the last setting for several minutes. And after a several minutes, it'll refresh to the new proxy settings. Only after that, I can access the internet page correctly.

While internet explorer will use the new proxy setting immediately. Why is it happening? How can I make chrome refresh proxy setting immediately?

my chrome version is: 52.0.2743.116 m

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you change the registry value directly, then those change won't be notified to other programs such as: chrome.

So the solution is: notify the internet changes to all the programs.

the script I wrote is autohotkey script, so I find the solution here:
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/19498-internet-explorer-windows-proxy-function/

In the script, the statements which trigger the notification is:

  `dllcall("wininet\InternetSetOptionW","int","0","int","39","int","0","int","0")
  dllcall("wininet\InternetSetOptionW","int","0","int","37","int","0","int","0")`

Hope this will help.